# Can I remove Android default link styling in webview

Tags: android, webview

When you click a link in the Android browser, the target link area gets highlighted with an orange box by default.  A longpress then opens up the context menu for link handling (copy, paste, new window, etc).  Is there a way to disable either / both of these in webview?  I'm using the [highlight code](http://wiki.github.com/madrobby/scriptaculous/effect-highlight) in scriptaculous and the default android link styling is being laid over top of the effect.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This might be useful: [How to Hide Android WebView Highlight Border](http://danbarnett.net/how-to-hide-android-webview-highlight-border-or-change-its-color-142.html)

The answer being: add this CSS `* { -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); }`.

Hopefully it is.

Comment: Exactly right!  Thanks so much.  I'm pasting the CSS here just in case that site ever disappears.

* {-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);}

Comment: @EnthuDeveloper it is css - so either in the css file for your page or in a style tag on the page itself.

Answer (score 11):

The suggested solution sets the color as transparent black:

```
* {
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Simply specifying the color as `transparent` should work:

```
* {
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: Just tested it (android 2.3.4), it doesn't. You cannot change the highlighting color, only make it disappear. And to do so, you must use rgba(X,X,X,0) syntax.