# disable mobile browser click/touch/tap feedback box

Tags: html, mobile

In an HTML 5 site a user, who's surfing through a mobile device, clicks a link.
The browser draws a box (rectangle) as a feedback (in addition to a sound).
Browser might mean Android 2.3's stock browser, or Opera Mobile.

Made some research about it but really, no (clear) solution.

**I'd like to avoid this (blue) box**. At least for iPhone and Android based devices. Any idea?

P.S I'm also using jQuery

Answer (score 49, accepted):

This is a duplicate of: [Can I remove Android default link styling in webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3376721/can-i-remove-android-default-link-styling-in-webview) and [iPad Safari: How to disable the quick blinking effect when a link has been hit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3516173/ipad-safari-how-to-disable-the-quick-blinking-effect-when-a-link-has-been-hit).

The answer being: add this CSS

```
* { -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); }
```

Comment: Correct, for some reason it did not work when asked, so thanks!

Answer (score 24):

I'm +1 to an answer, provided by bloopletech. 
But if you'd like to have this trick worked in an android native browser (Android Browser), use next:

```
* { 
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    -moz-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The blue outline you see on link is the result of an 'outline'.
To turn it off set:

```
outline: none;
```

Not sure why this has not yet been answered correctly.

Comment: Actually the outline isn't what OP was asking about.