# Removing active link styling in android web view

Tags: android, css, jquery-mobile, android-webview

I've tried [this old solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3376721/can-i-remove-android-default-link-styling-in-webview?rq=1) but it doesn't work.

I'm using android 4.4 which has a major update for the web view widget. My web application is based on jquery mobile

When I click on a link in my web application, the web view put an orange border on the active link.

Comment: I've added... feel free to ask for a specific information...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify `outline: none;` in your CSS to hide the focus ring. Here's some more information: http://devtacular.com/articles/bkonrad/how-to-remove-chromes-orange-outline/

However, be aware that users navigating using a keyboard may be relying on the orange outline to indicate which element currently has focus, so you should consider providing some other affordance for them.